# Excel - Doubleclick Grand Total Data / Unpivot Pivot Table / Convert to CSV - VB Script

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net, export

Good afternoon Team,

My issue is that i have an excel file that i get already pivoted. Unfortunately the raw data sheet ( data based on what the pivot is made) is not local or in a sheet in this excel. If i doubleclick manually on the Grand Total amount it does pops out the raw data.

My goal is to create either a vbs macro where it doubleclicks [(without any human interaction)even though i am unable to record a macro where i just doubleclick] the grand total amount, or either a vbscript to unpivot/extract the raw data of the pivot to get access to that data which i will later on export in an csv file.

Hope it makes sense, i ve been struggling with this for the past 2 days.

Thank you in advance

LE** i fixed it by using applicatin.doubleclick()